# Angular and Laravel authorization header CORS error

Tags: angular, laravel, cors

I have an interceptor in Angular for send angular to Laravel CORS

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token'),

});
let reqClone = req.clone({
    headers: headers
});
```

In Laravel's Middleware

```php
return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
```

I tried to access

```php
$request->header('authorization') // Laravel
```

but I recieve CORS related error

> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: You need to add Authorization to your Allow-Headers..

Comment: you can see example, please? and where does it place.

Comment: Sorry, on Mobile. ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With', ‘Authorization’);

Comment: I will try, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) plugin. I think that solve the problem.